# When I install redux core, is redux thunk will installed with it or I have to install redux thunk separately?

Tags: redux

npm install redux
npm install react-redux

I install only both of them. Is redux thunk included with it ?

Comment: The redux documentation will have that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Thunk is a middleware for Redux. It allows writing functions with logic inside that can interact with a Redux store's dispatch and getState methods.

Install using:

```
npm install redux-thunk

or

yarn add redux-thunk
```

The next step is to configure everything you can follow the documentation in https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Answer (score 0):

If you only install redux, then the answer is no. But with `npm install @reduxjs/toolkit`, it comes with it, so in this case answer is yes: With `redux-toolkit`, `redux-thunk` comes preinstalled with it.